# Life cycle of the idToken from SPA to third party application ( PHP or Java ) in using Firebase ID Tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire, firebase-security, firebase-admin

Working on a Single page application ( child application ) which is integrated by other several PHP application ( parent application ). The SPA takes care of signing in the user using Firebase ( Social and Email/password Login ). Once user has logged in idToken is passed to the other application ( Parent application ).

Task in Parent application is to fetch the same details of the user using same idToken. But when a API call is made to fecth User details using below method

> https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=[API_KEY]

where 
**API_KEY** is the application key - AIzaSyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXl1eblo_WgxA

**idToken** - the same which I get from child application.

I end up getting **MISSING_ID_TOKEN** error. What am I missing here ?
Do I need to re validate the idToken from the parent application ? If Yes how do we do it ? And how do we get further user details from there ?

Also these tokens are normally created for google accounts. How should be Facebook and email/password module handled ?

Please help me with the above scenario.

Much Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you passing a Google ID token or a Firebase ID token. Also why are you using the REST API when you already have angularfire to handle these calls for you?

Comment: @bojeil, The implementation is something like the angular application is used by multiple parent application like a component. Currently Google Id token is passed. But question is do we need to validate that token in Parent application as well ? Second question what should be passed if it is Facebood login ?

Comment: I don't understand your application. That said, you can't use a Google ID token or Facebook access token with the `getAccountInfo` endpoint. That accepts a Firebase ID token only. You need to exchange these 3rd party credentials for a Firebase ID token and then use that with `getAccountInfo`. Normally you should validate the Google ID token but if you are passing it to Firebase Auth backend, they would validate it for you before returning the Firebase ID token.